# InternetCrackUrl() function

Tags: c++, parsing, winapi, url, wininet

I've got a little problem with this function when I'm trying to crack my URL in URL_COMPONENTS structure, the value of HostName and urlPath members stays on '\0' and meanwhile it's so, I have the true Length of both(HostName and urlPath members).
what is the problem?, it' would be my pleasure if you answer by code.

Thanks and best wishes,
John Smith.

```
URL_COMPONENTS urlcomponents;
urlcomponents.dwStructSize=sizeof(URL_COMPONENTS);
urlcomponents.dwHostNameLength=10;
urlcomponents.dwPasswordLength=10;
urlcomponents.dwSchemeLength=10;
urlcomponents.dwUrlPathLength=10;
urlcomponents.dwUserNameLength=10;
urlcomponents.dwExtraInfoLength=10;
urlcomponents.lpszExtraInfo=extraInfo;
urlcomponents.lpszHostName=hostName;
urlcomponents.lpszPassword=passwordSet;
urlcomponents.lpszScheme=schemeUrl;
urlcomponents.lpszUrlPath=fileUrlPath;
urlcomponents.lpszUserName=userName;
//urlcomponents.nPort=80;

std::string originUrl="http://s1.asandownload.com/mobile/android/application/Color.Effect.Booth.Pro.v1.4.2_AsanDl.com.apk";

InternetCrackUrl(originUrl.c_str(),originUrl.Length(),0,&urlcomponents);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem solved and I'm Gonna share it here :D

it's so obvious that when GetLastError returns ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
You need to increase the Length or size of something for god sake!!! :D
so, I increased it :D ,
ex:

```
urlcomponents.dwHostNameLength=1024;
```

cause my buffer size was

```
=new char [1024];
```

AWESOME!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `originUrl.c_str()` to the `dwUrlLength` parameter of `InternetCrackUrl()`.  You need to pass either `0` or `originUrl.length()` instead.  You should also be checking the return value of `InternetCrackUrl()` for failure.

```
if (!InternetCrackUrl(originUrl.c_str(),originUrl.length(),0,&urlcomponents))
{
    DWORD ErrCode - GetLastError();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yea, So Sorry I just wrote it worng in here and in Real Code I tested both originUrl.Length() and 0 and they didn't worked.
btw when I use GetLastError it Says :
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

122 (0x7A)

The data area passed to a system call is too small.

what should I do ?