# Calling InternetCrackUrl from Powershell

Tags: powershell, wininet, winhttp

I am an idiot for this... Does anybody has examples on how to call WinINet InternetCrackUrl from powershell?
The API ref is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcrackurla).

I want a very robust way to parse URLs, I have tried some regex samples out there and none seem to do the job,

Comment: [InternetCrackURL Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036494/internetcrackurl-function)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the [`[System.Uri]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri) already built-in to .NET - PowerShell even ships with a `[uri]` type accelerator for it!

```
$aURL = [uri]'https://some.address.tld/with/a/path?and=a&few=query&params&even#anchors'
```

I invite you to explore the properties of the resulting `[uri]` object yourself, but these are probably the main ones you'd be interested in

```
$aURL |Format-Table Scheme,Authority,AbsolutePath,Query,Fragment

Scheme Authority        AbsolutePath Query                        Fragment
------ ---------        ------------ -----                        --------
https  some.address.tld /with/a/path ?and=a&few=query&params&even #anchors
```